# Can I pass an array into system exec.vi in LabVIEW?

Tags: labview

I am trying to pass an array from LabVIEW into system exec.vi which will run a python script that takes the array as an argument. Is there any possible way to do this ? Are there ways to communicate LabVIEW with python ?

The LabVIEW version I'm using is strictly LabVIEW 2014.

Comment: LabVIEW 2018 adds support for direct communication with Python.

Comment: How big is the array? The obvious options for small, medium and large arrays are (small) format the array into a string which you pass as an input parameter to the python script, e.g. "1, 2, 3, 4, 5", and read with `sys.argv`; (medium) format the array into a string which you pass to `standard input` of System Exec.vi and read in the Python script with one or more `input` commands; (large) write the array to a temporary file, pass the filename to the script and read it in the script.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check [Python Integration Toolkit for LabVIEW by Enthought](http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/cs/nid/213990)? It is payed, but allows to call Python scripts from LabVIEW...
Regarding passing array as argument - when you'll check the toolkit, I guess there would be some examples of how to call scripts with arguments, so you could reuse it.

Also, you could try to follow the following description - [Python - Command Line Arguments](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm), and implement parsing of command-line arguments on Python script side. And the array will be passed in as string, part of system exec input string.

Answer (score 0):

Starting in [LabVIEW 2018](https://labviewwiki.org/wiki/LabVIEW_2018), native Python calling was added.

LabVIEW also ships with examples. To find the examples go to the Help menu, and then Find Example...  The Example Finder includes a search by terms.